# Compiling main.c with c++ static library fails but works with c++ dynamic library (edited)

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, static-libraries, static-linking

I am working with the TensorFlow repository and have used it to build both a static and dynamic library from c++ code using Bazel.

I am trying to use the static library (.a) with a c script (main.c). At compile time I get a huge amount of 'undefined reference' errors.

However, if I used the dynamic version (.so) of the library it successfully compiles and runs.

I have tested the libraries with a c++ script (main.cpp), this works for both.

I have seen online that it could be something to do with using extern "C" but it seems odd that it would work for the dynamic library and not the static?

## Further Information

Lets say the library is `libconv2d`
I am building the dynamic library with:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "conv2d",
    deps = [
        ":runtime_conv2d",
        ],
    linkshared = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

where `runtime_conv2d` is built [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4403d5523d707c37fd251eac08bfafebd3263307/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/BUILD#L739) and the function I am using from the library is:

- [header file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4403d5523d707c37fd251eac08bfafebd3263307/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/runtime_conv2d.h#L25)
- [source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4403d5523d707c37fd251eac08bfafebd3263307/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/runtime_conv2d.cc#L25)

For the static library I am using [this](https://github.com/slackhq/grpc-hack/blob/master/cc_library_static.bzl) to build the library using Bazel.

When compiling (using clang-12 for requirement purposes):

```
clang-12 main.c module.ll libconv2d.a
```

where `main.c` calls a function in the LLVM `module.ll` which in turn calls the function in the library.

This throws a huge error, a small section of which can be seen below:

```
libllvm_static_test1.a(jit_gates_reduction.pic.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4dnnl4impl3cpu3x6421jit_gates_reduction_tE[_ZTIN4dnnl4impl3cpu3x6421jit_gates_reduction_tE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
libllvm_static_test1.a(cache_blob_id.pic.o): In function `dnnl::impl::cache_blob_id_t::get(dnnl_engine const*, dnnl::impl::primitive_desc_t const*)':
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZN4dnnl4impl15cache_blob_id_t3getEPK11dnnl_enginePKNS0_16primitive_desc_tE+0x9a): undefined reference to `std::__once_callable'
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZN4dnnl4impl15cache_blob_id_t3getEPK11dnnl_enginePKNS0_16primitive_desc_tE+0xb1): undefined reference to `std::__once_call'
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZN4dnnl4impl15cache_blob_id_t3getEPK11dnnl_enginePKNS0_16primitive_desc_tE+0xd8): undefined reference to `__once_proxy'
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZN4dnnl4impl15cache_blob_id_t3getEPK11dnnl_enginePKNS0_16primitive_desc_tE+0xec): undefined reference to `std::__throw_system_error(int)'
libllvm_static_test1.a(cache_blob_id.pic.o): In function `void std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_range_insert<unsigned char const*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xf5): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x1d7): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
cache_blob_id.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE15_M_range_insertIPKhEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EET_S9_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x28f): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
```

Comment: Same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048176/compiling-main-c-with-c-static-library-fails-but-works-with-c-dynamic-librar

Comment: A static library is nothing more than a collection of object files. Linking with a static library is like linking with the individual object files themselves. As such, there's no information about dependencies of the static library. Which in turns means you have to link with all dependencies yourself.

Comment: With that said, don't delete and repost the same question multiple times. If you want to improve your question, then ***[edit]*** it instead.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a re-post of an already closed question.  Follow the suggestion made both here, and at the original post to improve your question.

Comment: Give the guy a break, this is a much improved version of the original question, which was edited only after it had been closed. Since questions almost never get reopened even when improved what alternative does a poster have other than reposting a question.

Comment: @john Editing a question push it back to the top of the (normal) front-page feed. It can let people that closed it see the question again, and reward the poster with voting to open it again as well as voting up the question (or remove down-votes) if it's improved enough. Not to mention that new people who didn't see it the first time will now get a chance. And if more people are like me, then they might keep the post open in a tab for a couple of hours, maybe even a couple of days, in the hope that it improves so they can help the poster.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's my experience that even when asked for information is provided questions almost never get reopened.

Comment: Thankyou @john I am new to this so appreciate your support.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please could you develop your answer? How would I do that / is that even possible?

Comment: What other libraries does `libconv2d` depend on? You need to list them when building (add them at the end, using the `-l` (lower-case L)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok thanks, would I do this recursively such that if  libconv2d depended on libA and libA depended on libB I would have to add both libA and libB?

Comment: That depends on the libraries. If `libA` is a static library then you need to include `libB` as well. Otherwise if `libA` is a dynamic library then it's not needed. For simplicity: Add one dependency at a time, until you no longer get errors.